# multiple row insert into table using array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$item=array(55,56,57,58);
$qty=array(11,111,1111,11111);
$tax=array(10,10,10,10);
$uprice=array(22,222,2222,22222);
```

I want this data to insert into table in single query with format like this-

```
 product_id  quantity unit_price tax
 55          11       22         10
 56          111      222        10
 57          1111     2222       10
 58          11111    22222      10
```

and my php script is like this, but i unable to inset data into table. please help me.

```
$itm_list=array(" product_id='$item',
            quantity='$qty',
          unit_price='$tax',
          tax_amount='$uprice' ");

foreach($itm_list as $k=>$v){   
$q=mysql_query("insert into invoice_items set $v ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Are you inserting or updating..?

Comment: i have inserting data

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to put query in php loops it may slow your code.. Here is the way to run efficiently..

```
$item=array(55,56,57,58);
$qty=array(11,111,1111,11111);
$tax=array(10,10,10,10);
$uprice=array(22,222,2222,22222);

$str = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($item);$i++)
{
  $str .= '("'.$item[$i].'","'.$qty[$i].'","'.$tax[$i].'","'$uprice[$i].'"),';

}
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
$sql='insert into invoice_items values '.$str;
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php 
$item=array(55,56,57,58);
$qty=array(11,111,1111,11111);
$tax=array(10,10,10,10);
$uprice=array(22,222,2222,22222);

$row = array();
foreach($item as $key => $value) {
    $row[] = array($value,$qty[$key],$uprice[$key],$tax[$key]);
}

foreach($row as $r) {
    $string = "'".implode("', '",$r)."'";
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoice_items(product_id,quantity,unit_price,tax)VALUES($string)");
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php 
foreach ($item as $key => $value): 
    $v[] = array(" product_id='".$value."',
            quantity='".$qty[$key]."',
           unit_price='".$tax[$key]."',
           tax_amount='".$uprice[$key]."' ");

     $fields = implode(',',array_keys($v));
     $val = array_values($v);
     $values = "'".implode("', '",$val)."'";
     $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoice_items($fields)VALUES($values)");
endforeach; 
?>
```

or you can check this link perhaps 
https://www.udemy.com/blog/sql-insert-multiple-rows/

Comment: He wants 1 query, just contact the values and do 1 query at the end.

Comment: He is inserting the data in DB as the given table format you can see in the question. And how will you insert all rows in a single query without foreach loop?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com `INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values1), (values2), (values3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$item=array(55,56,57,58);
$qty=array(11,111,1111,11111);
$tax=array(10,10,10,10);
$uprice=array(22,222,2222,22222);
for($i=0;$i<count($item);$i++)
{
   $sql='insert into invoice_items values($item[$i],$qty[$i],$tax[$i],$uprice[$i)';
   mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working :

```
$dbh=mysql_connect ("host-name", "user","password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database-name"); 

$item=array(55,56,57,58);
$qty=array(11,111,1111,11111);
$tax=array(10,10,10,10);
$uprice=array(22,222,2222,22222);
for($i=0;$i<count($tax);$i++)
{
   $sql='insert into invoice_items values($item[$i],$qty[$i],$tax[$i],$uprice[$i)';
   mysql_query($sql);
}

mysql_close($dbh);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this one

```
<?php 
foreach ($item as $key => $value): 
    $v = array(" product_id='".$value."',
            quantity='".$qty[$key]."',
           unit_price='".$tax[$key]."',
           tax_amount='".$uprice[$key]."' ");
$q=mysql_query("insert into invoice_items set $v ") or die(mysql_error());    
endforeach;
```

?>

Comment: SQL query fro your code will `insert into invoice_items set Array`